# Different rotation of image on PC and through input type file

Tags: javascript, jpeg, exif, exif-js

Image is in `jpeg` format and it's being shown as it should on my PC (I'm using Ubuntu), but once I try to upload it through `<input type="file"...` while browsing for it, it displays as if it is rotated 90 degrees to the right.
I have part of code in my app which rotates images based on `EXIF.getTag(this, 'Orientation')` parameter and it's returning number 8 for this case which implies that the image should be rotated to the left for 90 degrees, even it shouldn't (because it's already rotated on the PC).

What is causing this?

**EDIT:**

I found images containing exif parameter [here](https://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/01/uiimageorientation-exif-orientation-sample-images/). So once I download them using provided link, they are being properly shown on the PC, but are rotated when uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main metadata tags for specifying image orientation:

`Orientation: [TopLeft, BottomRight, RightTop, LeftBottom]`

and

`exif:Orientation: [1, 3, 6, 8]`

I suspect your image was taken by a device, which uses `exif:Orientation` meta tag. Ubuntu default image viewer supports `exif:Orientation` and thus it displays the image correctly. Browsers, however, do not support this tag (for backward compatibility reasons) and they have to fall back to the default orientation which is rotated 90 deg to right in your case.

You could solve your issue by supplementing your images with the `Orientation` meta tag. This could be done with most image viewing software by simply rotating your image and saving it in place (in Ubuntu you will see the image rotated properly, so simply rotate it in any direction and rotate it back and save).

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the case. But the problem is that I need to do this somehow through code, because this problem was reported by the users who use app I am working on. Is there a way to do the process that I would normally do through "image viewing software" using JavaScript?

Comment: @nikname You could create 3 CSS classes for each rotation angle and apply them according to the output of the `EXIF.getTag(this, 'Orientation')`. There's also a tool you can use to handle the issue for you: [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image)

Comment: I saw it and probably gonna use it. Thank you